# How to make last element visible on screen in a dialog?

Tags: css, chakra-ui

I am working on a problem, where I do not know how to make the last element visible when screen is resized. It is best explained in the video below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/samy2.jpg

I am using Chakra-UI, but if this could be solved using raw CSS, that would be a great help. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try add a max-height to your element :

```
.yourMenu{
max-height : 70vh;
overflow:auto;
}
```

It will add a scrollbar when the element is too small. That's the easiest solution.

You can also go further using media screen and set a special param for "small height devices" :

```
@media screen and (max-height: 700px) {
/* Some special "small height screen menu display here */
}
```

Like maybe reduce font-size ? Padding ? break menu in 2 parts ?